# Photoshop script - export specific layersets by name

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I have layersets as here

[image: 1]

I wish to merge visible layers (by copying) and export as png from each layerset.

So, I'd have 1.png, 2.png, 3.png, 4.png, and 5.png

I can access the layersets by name, but don't know how to save afterwards.

```
var layersetNames = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
for (n = 0; n < layersetNames.length; n++) {
    var layersetName = layersetNames[n];

    // get layerset by name
    var layerset = app.activeDocument.layerSets.getByName(layersetName);
    
    // copy & merge visible layers within this layerset

    // save the merged layer as .png
    
}

// after done saving, delete all the merged layers as if nothing had happened.
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is destructive, (ie you don't worry about the state the psd is afterwards) and you're just going through the layers, saving out a png each time, then you don't need to do the copy and merge. You do however, need to switch the layers visibility on and off:

```
var layersetNames = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
for (n = 0; n < layersetNames.length; n++)

{
   var layersetName = layersetNames[n];

   // get layerset by name
   var layerset = app.activeDocument.layerSets.getByName(layersetName);

   layerset.visible = true;

   // save the merged layer as .png
   png_it("C:\\temp\\" + layersetName + ".png"); // change this

   layerset.visible = false;
}


function png_it(afilePath)
{
  // app.activeDocument.mergeVisibleLayers();

  // save as a png
  var pngFile = new File(afilePath);
  pngSaveOptions = new PNGSaveOptions();
  pngSaveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.STANDARDBASELINE;
  pngSaveOptions.interlaced = false;

  activeDocument.saveAs(pngFile, pngSaveOptions, false, Extension.LOWERCASE);
}
```

Comment: Some of the properties (`matte`, `embedColorProfile`, `formatOptions`, and `quality`) that you are setting in your `pngSaveOptions` look like `JPEGSaveOptions` to me.

Comment: I wouldn't be at all surprised :D They're mentioned [here](https://developer.adobe.com/photoshop/uxp/2022/ps_reference/objects/saveoptions/pngsaveoptions/)

Comment: That’s interesting - I guess Adobe have extended them in [UXP](https://developer.adobe.com/photoshop/uxp/2022/). I was thinking ExtendScript, so when I run `var pngSaveOptions = new PNGSaveOptions(); pngSaveOptions.reflect.properties;` it only prints _`interlaced`_, _`typename`_ (and _`__proto__`_). However I currently only have access to an old version of PhotoShop.

Comment: The other interesting thing is that Photoshop doesn't kick up any errors, and saves out the .png fine - even with extra options that don't work.